# Difference between final variables vs static final variables

Tags: java

I was just studying about final data members and i thought what would be the difference final variables vs static final variables ??

---

I understand that a field that is both static and final has only one piece of storage, and final variable will have storages associated with every instance.

But even if i declare a variable only final, then it remains the same for all the objects as i need to initialize them in the program itself and not at the run time.

---

So, basically there is no difference between the two except for the memory related issue ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> But even if i declare a variable only final, then it remains the same
>   for all the objects as i need to initialize them in the program itself
>   and not at the run time.

No, non-static final members can be initialized in the constructor. They cannot be re-assigned after that.

Comment: Can i initialize the value of a final variable at run time via user input ??

Comment: Only if you are calling the constructor after the user-input is taken. It cannot be changed after the constructor is called.

Comment: Only if it is part of the constructor. A way around this is to have another class read in the value first, then create your object with the final variable once you know the data.

Comment: Sorry to bother you more.. I am new to java as you can see.. is it possible to call a constructor depending on the user input ?? And if yes, can you give me an example !!

Comment: @user1262062.. for that, we'll need some code as to how you are trying to do this. Perhaps a separate question?

Comment: Okay.. I will be asking something on that soon !! But before that i need to try it out myself !!

Comment: Sorry, but you can set the value in run time. Check my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `final` means you can assign only one time the value to the variable. The `final` can be use in many scopes and is very useful, in a object property you must (and forced) to set the value on the declaration, or in the constructor or in the initialization block of the object.

And the `static` is to set the scope of the variable, that means in a class property that value is storage inside the class, and can be access even without an object, when you use `static final` or `final static` you must (and forced) to set the value on the declaration or inside a static initialization code of the class.

Example:

```
public class NewClass {

    static final int sc = 123; //I recommend to use this declaration style.
    final static int scc;
    final int o = 123;
    final int oo;
    final int ooo;

    static {
        scc = 123;
    }

    {
        oo = 123;
    }

    public NewClass() {
        ooo = 123;
    }

    void method(final int p) {
//        p=123; //Error, the value is only assigned at the call of the method.

        final int m = 123;
        final int mm;
        mm = 123;
//        mm = 456; //Error, you can set the value only once.
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(m + p); //You still can reach the variables.
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

final variables : A variable declared final will be a constant, its value can not be changed, and can be initialized in the constructor.

static final variable : This must be initialized, either during the declaration or in the static initializer block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes -> They look pretty similar but there are some changes between them! and they are :-
**non-static final variables** =

- This can be declared and initialized at a time and also we can just declared and initialize using constructor
- Once we initialized we can not override it
- these variables can be accessed by its "Name" inside the non-static method but inside the static method we can access it using the object Ref only.

**static final variables**

- This must be declared and initialized at same time only.
- Once we initialized we can not override it and if we are not initializing it we will get compilation error
- this variables can be accessed by it "Name" it self at any place and any where in the project

I hope this was helpful and happy learning!!